# display items' values in bar chart in Jpgraph

Tags: codeigniter, bar-chart, jpgraph

I am using jpgraph bar chart. It all works fine but there is one thing I could not really figure it out. I need to display the value of each bar on the top of that bar (column) but it seems like I am missing something that I cant do it.

I have tried using the following:

```
$bplot->value->Show();
```

But yet it does not work! Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Could someone please tell me if this is ever possible?

Comment: Can you post your entire graph php code please?

Answer (score 12):

It is an old question, but as I had the same problem and I solved it, I'm posting this answer as a future reference.

My problem was the order of the invoked methods. You MUST call `Show` **after** addnig the plot to the graph. As an example:

```
$graph = new \Graph($width, $height);

[... init graph ...]

$plot = new \BarPlot($datay);
$graph->Add($plot);
$plot->value->Show();
$plot->value->SetColor("black","darkred"); 
$plot->value->SetFormat('%01.2f');
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Call the Show() method after you've added the plot to the graph.

```
$graph->Add($plot);
$plot->value->Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

This example shows it can be done, and it gives a complete example of how to pull it off:

http://enacit1.epfl.ch/php/jpgraph/docs/html/exframes/frame_example20.1.html

I'd be glad to look at your code and troubleshoot if you require help beyond this.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the value on top of the bar:

```
$bplot->SetValuePos('top');
```

Changing the angle:

```
$bplot->value->SetAngle(90);
```

Hiding value that are 0:

```
$bplot->value->HideZero();
```